# Qt QHBoxLayout percentage size

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How can I maintain an aspect ratio between two QHBoxLayouts?

For instance I want a QHBoxLayout to be one third of the entire window width and the other to be two thirds of the entire window width:
[image]

How can I achieve this? I tried messing with the size hints of the controls in them but that didn't work out

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[void QSizePolicy::setHorizontalStretch(uchar stretchFactor)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#setHorizontalStretch)

Example:

```
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(form);

QWidget* left = new QWidget(form);
QSizePolicy spLeft(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
spLeft.setHorizontalStretch(1);
left->setSizePolicy(spLeft);
layout->addWidget(left);

QWidget* right = new QWidget(form);
QSizePolicy spRight(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
spRight.setHorizontalStretch(2);
right->setSizePolicy(spRight);
layout->addWidget(right);
```

Comment: Thank you, I would also add that if you click on the QHBoxLayout in the QT Designer and choose "morph into -> widget" you can set HorizontalStretch visually without the code.

Answer (score 13):

The answer of [york.beta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2009882/york-beta) is working, but I prefer much less code.

At least the sizePolicy is by default Prefered/Prefered.

> The default policy is Preferred/Preferred, which means that the widget can be freely resized, but prefers to be the size sizeHint() returns.

You can simply use the *second* parameter of *addWidget* to stretch the widgets.

```
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout( this );
layout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
layout->setSpacing( 0 );

QPushButton *left = new QPushButton( "133px", this );
left->setStyleSheet( "QPushButton{border: 1px solid red;}" );
QPushButton *right = new QPushButton( "267px", this );
right->setStyleSheet( "QPushButton{border: 1px solid blue;}" );

layout->addWidget( left, 33 );
layout->addWidget( right, 66 );

this->setLayout( layout );
this->setFixedWidth( 400 );
```

[image]

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget

and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop

Comment: This is my preferred answer for simplicity, succinctness and avoiding the stylesheets.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the layoutStretch property:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors

In your case it'd be

```
<layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="1,2">
```

Comment: This is actually a better and simpler way. To explain it a bit more, the 'stretch' property uses comma separated number to set the children elements' size proportion to each other. In case of three children, use "1,2,2" will give each widget size of 1/5, 2/5, 2/5 respectively of the whole.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the sizePolicy for the widgets and set a higher [horizontalStretch](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsizepolicy.html#setHorizontalStretch) for the widget in the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setStretchFactor` method:

```
layout->addWidget(left);
layout->addWidget(right);
layout->setStretchFactor(left, 1);
layout->setStretchFactor(right, 2);
```