# C++ QT : How to set margins and size properties of QWidget in percentage

Tags: c++, qt

Actually i want to create a QHBoxLayout with two widgets as children and these widgets size should be in percentage of current window size,this should also works after re sizing my window. how to set position of a widget if i want to position this at exact half of Qt::AlignLeft and Qt::AlignCenter position.

Comment: I guess this one answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561516/qt-qhboxlayout-percentage-size More information can be found in the Qt Docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-basiclayouts.html

Comment: I have solved my first problem by using QWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,  QSizePolicy::Expanding); looking for second one now

Comment: This is discussed in the links I put in my comment